# Establish a TCP Socket connection using an intermediate host

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming

I need to establish a Socket connection (TCP) between two hosts (say host1 and host2) in Java. But looks like I can't do that because of a firewall. Though there's a third host (say host3) which is accessible from both host1 and host2 and I think can be used as an intermediate for this connection.

So basically, I want to send a request from host1 (client) to host3, which redirects my request to host2 (server).

Could you please let me know how can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to be running a program implementing the proxy functionality on the intermediate host. your program should receive all the data from the sender and then forward it to the destination. There are many different free tools available for the purpose.

Comment: Thanks Raza. Do you happen to know any of the proxy servers where the learning curve involved would be less?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could establish a SSH tunnel with

```
ssh host3 -L4321:host2:6523
```

and then connect from host1 to host3 on port 4321. This effectively gets redirected to port 6523 on host2.

---

A similiar option could be to have `ssh` provide a SOCKS server.

```
ssh host3 -D 6543
```

and then use `curl` instead of `wget`.

Then you can do

```
curl http://host2/foo/bar --socks4 localhost:6543
```

(untested, `--socks4a` and `--socks5` could be an option as well...)

This `ssh` command creates a SOCKS server locally which tunnels the connection attempts to the ssh server, which in turn executes them.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and it kind of worked for me. But I encountered another issue which I had not taken into account. I also need to use 'wget' to retrieve some data from host2, which doesn't seem to work with SSH tunnel. Any other ideas?

Comment: you can use scp instead of wget

Comment: ...if host has a SSH server and the user has an account for it.

Comment: The device (host2) doesn't have a ssh server. So I am stuck with wget.

Comment: I googled a little more. Here's what I found. My best bet is to create socks5 proxy server at host3. I started with Squid, but looks like it has support for only HTTP requests. I am not sure at this point of time if my TCP requests will go through (still working on it). I am also trying to find a tool for SOCKS, but no luck as of now. Do you guys happen to know any?

Comment: Yes. As said, `ssh` and `curl`.

Comment: Curl didn't work either. This is the error I get:

"curl: (52) Failed to receive SOCKS4 connect request ack."

Same thing happens with SOCKS5.